# Filter products by custom product attribute et post meta data in a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, product

I have already filtered by category, but don't know how to filter products by custom attributes or meta values

code:

```
$key="naam"; //custom attribute name
$value="test";// custom value
$query_custom = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value);
$meta_query[] = $query_custom ;

$args=array('meta_query'=>$meta_query, 'product_cat' => 'activiteiten','posts_per_page' => 10,'post_type' => 'product');



$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

`

[image: See image for custom attributes]

Comment: You can find a working solution for this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74200775/how-can-i-filter-woocommerce-shop-products-product-loop-by-their-custom-produc

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of a query involving:

- product category filtering
- post meta value filtering (meta query)
- product attribute value filtering (tax query)

The code:

```
$products = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',

    // 1. Product category filter
    'product_cat' => 'clothing',

    // 2. The Post meta query part (filtering by post meta value)
    'meta_query' => array( array(
         'key'     => '_price',
         'value'   => 5,
         'type'    => 'numeric',
         'compare' => '>',
    ), ),

    // 3. The taxonomy meta query part (filtering by term values)
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'pa_color', // Product attribute taxonomy: always start with 'pa_'
        'field'    => 'slug', // Can be 'term_id', 'slug' or 'name'
        'terms'    => array('blue'),
    ), ),
) );

// Testing output
if( $products->have_posts() ) : 
echo '<ul>'
while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
echo '<li class="post-id-' . get_the_id() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
echo '</ul>'
endif;
```

Tested and working:

Official reference documentation for Wordpress `WP_Query`:

- [`WP_Query` and Custom fields parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)
- [`WP_Query` and Taxonomy parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using following code.

```
            $args = array(
              'meta_query'=> array(
                array(
                  'key' => 'vote', // here use your field name
                  'compare' => '=', // comparison sign
                  'value' => 5, // value using that you can search

                )
              ),
              'product_cat' => 'activiteiten',
              'posts_per_page' => 10,
              'post_type' => 'product'
            ) );

            query_posts( $args ); // get all the posts data using above filter.
```

query_posts is used to find out the posts with list of arguments `meta_query` is used in your case to find the matched custom field data.

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written