# How can I filter WooCommerce shop products (product loop) by their custom product attributes?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a simple way to filter all WooCommerce shop products inside the shop loop by their custom product attributes, as you can see below:

[image]

The attributes can have a lot of values with special chars (besides normal Latin chars) like `ü` or `ß`.

I've done a lot of research inside Stack Overflow, but was unable to find a good solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I started my question here, I thought that will be an easy trip – haha. Since I got no answers in time, I've started researching again and found a huge pile of unanswered or non-specific questions on Stack Overflow. A fast and simple solution would have been adding all attributes as global attributes and use the taxonomy query filter to check against each product like `pa_xxxx`.

I mean, this solution totally works but will enhance the manual effort by a huge number of time depending on your amount of products. So no option for me (> 4000 products).

During my research, I've found an answer which used a WooCommerce filter hook named `woocommerce_product_query_meta_query` to check if there is any given value inside the serialized custom attributes stored inside the `wp_postmeta` table under the `_product_attributes` key for each product:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'filter_woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_product_query_meta_query( array $meta_query ): array {
    if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() ) {
        $meta_query[] = [
            'key'     => '_product_attributes',
            'value'   => 'grün',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ];
    }

    return $meta_query;
}
```

(I've added a check for shop or categories page)

At the first point, I was really happy because it worked. But minutes later I've realized, that this design is completely useless since it's ignoring all attribute names and just searches for `grün` and `grün` can be anything from a color to a nice meadow. So no option for a precise filter.

Then I remembered, that I can use non-greedy RegEx within MySQL. Not simple to me, but possible.

Since the hook gets parsed inside `$wpdb` later on, I've tried to find out what compare operants are allowed:

```
array( '=', 'IN', 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', 'REGEXP', 'RLIKE', '>', '>=', '<', '<=' )
```

Great, we have `REGEXP` available. So I've started writing my RegEx which checks inside serialized attributes. Hours later, I'm proud to present you my function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'filter_woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_product_query_meta_query( array $meta_query ): array {
    if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() ) {
        $quoted_key   = preg_quote( 'farbe', '/' );
        $quoted_value = preg_quote( 'grün', '/' );

        $meta_query[] = [
            'key'     => '_product_attributes',
            'value'   => 's:[0-9]+:"' . $quoted_key . '";[a-z]:[0-9]+:\{[a-z]:[0-9]+:"name";[a-z]:[0-9]+:"([a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9?!+*-_.:,;=&%$/()@<> ]+)";[a-z]:[0-9]+:"value";[a-z]:[0-9]+:"(' . $quoted_value . '[ ";]|([a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9?!+*-_.:,;=&%$/()@<> ]+ \| )+(' . $quoted_value . '[ ";]))',
            'compare' => 'REGEXP'
        ];
    }

    return $meta_query;
}
```

To explain my RegEx a bit, I'll show you an example of a serialized attributes string directly out of my DB:

> a:2:{s:5:"farbe";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:5:"Farbe";s:5:"value";s:12:"Grün |
> Gelb";s:8:"position";i:0;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:0;}s:7:"groesse";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"Größe";s:5:"value";s:5:"S
> |
> M";s:8:"position";i:1;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:0;}}

As you can see above, inside my function, we want to search for a key named `farbe` and check if it contains a value `grün`. When you check my data example, you can see, that we have a correct dataset matching my search.

Before digging into my RegEx, I want to explain the use of `preg_qoute()`. Since we have a RegEx, it can happen that we have strings containing special signs which will be recognized as part of the RegEx if we don't escape them. So we use the above function to do so.

So let's dig into my RegEx (since we can not use greedy RegEx, we need to build everything until we find our values):

- `s:[0-9]+:"` This part should find the beginning of an attribute like `s:5:"` which starts with a `s:` and any number between `0-9` until over by using a `+` followed by a `"`
- Now we can insert our key `' . $quoted_key . '` e.g. farbe which will directly come after a `"` sign
- Now we want to continue until we reach the real name field (not WooCommerce generated key) by using `";[a-z]:[0-9]+:\{[a-z]:[0-9]+:"`. We're again matching all possible serialized structure values here. As you can see, we also need to escape the opening `{` of the attribute set, including the name and the values
- At this point we will not pass a name but expect one by using `"name";[a-z]:[0-9]+:"([a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9?!+*-_.:,;=&%$/()@<> ]+)";` We allow the name to include all signs defined inside `[]`. We also include a pattern to still match the serialized string structure and close everything up with `";` again
- Finally we have our value checking part `[a-z]:[0-9]+:"value";[a-z]:[0-9]+:"(' . $quoted_value . '[ ";]|([a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9?!+*-_.:,;=&%$/()@<> ]+ \| )+(' . $quoted_value . '[ ";]))`. At the beginning, we try to match the serialized string structure again `[a-z]:[0-9]+:"` followed by the `value` identifier. Now it gets tricky. As you can see, I pass the qouted value to 2 loops. One to check if the value is placed at the beginning, the other to check within the values, separated by a `|` sign and ending with `";` again

I don't want to describe every single RegEx part, but I think you get the idea. Since I'm not a RegEx professional, the RegEx can may include optimization effort. Also, I'm not covering all available languages or signs yet since I just don't need them atm.

You can also put a PHP `foreach` loop around, which loops over a set of values to add the RegEx multiple times with different values to the `$meta_query` array. Since I want to keep things simple, I intentionally decided to not use value groups like `(grün|rot|gelb)` since it seems to have an error potential.

You can find the RegEx inside the editor: https://extendsclass.com/regex/6cc8142

I hope I can help you a bit with this tutorial and made your day just a bit better. Feel free to post your improvements to my RegEx. Cheers.

**Update: 26.10.2022**

My above solution works for `AND` relations inside the DB. This means, for example: `WHERE color = red AND blue AND green`. In case you want to extend the amount of products being displayed by adding another attribute check to the query, you should use an `OR` relation inside the query by nesting the query itself and adding a key for `relation`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'filter_woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_product_query_meta_query( array $meta_query ): array {
    if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() ) {
        $quoted_key   = preg_quote( 'farbe', '/' );
        $quoted_value = preg_quote( 'grün', '/' );

        $meta_query[] = [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [
                'key'     => '_product_attributes',
                'value'   => 's:[0-9]+:"' . $quoted_key . '";[a-z]:[0-9]+:\{[a-z]:[0-9]+:"name";[a-z]:[0-9]+:"([a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9?!+*-_.:,;=&%$/()@<> ]+)";[a-z]:[0-9]+:"value";[a-z]:[0-9]+:"(' . $quoted_value . '[ ";]|([a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9?!+*-_.:,;=&%$/()@<> ]+ \| )+(' . $quoted_value . '[ ";]))',
                'compare' => 'REGEXP'
            ]
            // Add multiple arrays like the one above here to extend the check
        ];
    }

    return $meta_query;
}
```

If you want to add another attribute check, you need to add another child array inside the main array after the first child array.

Comment: If I helped you, please give me a thumbs up :)